# In the GDK Level Sample, should SensorManager.getOrientation() work just as well as the atan() method?

Tags: android, google-glass

I was playing with the [GDK Level Sample](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-level-sample) and trying to add yaw and pitch indication to the existing roll indication. I was able to get the pitch angle working using a similar call to `Math.atan2()` in `LevelRenderer.computeOrientation()`, but then I discovered there's an API `SensorManager.getOrientation()` that sounds like it does that math for me. However, when I changed to code to call that function, I got all zeros instead of what I was expecting.

Is this method only valid in certain situations? I see they use it in the [Compass Sample](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample/blob/master/src/com/google/android/glass/sample/compass/OrientationManager.java) in `onSensorChanged()`.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you making sure that you're using the correct sensors with each of these approaches? The Level sample uses the `GRAVITY` sensor, which gives you a vector representing the direction and magnitude of gravity, so you can compute the arctangent directly from those values. The Compass uses `ROTATION_VECTOR`, which needs to be converted into a rotation matrix and then passed to `getOrientation`.

Comment: That's probably it. I was passing all zeros as the rotation matrix, because I thought it was an output argument. What's also confusing me is that `getOrientation()` is static on `SensorManager`, so I thought it was synthesized from several different sensors.

Comment: According to [this discussion](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/2010-06/msg00218.html), the static getOrientation() method doesn't talk to the sensors at all, but rather simply does math on the matrix to give me roll, pitch, and yaw angles.

Is there not a  sensor type that manages all that for me?

Comment: That's correct -- `getOrientation` is just a math helper. The sensor `TYPE_ORIENTATION` was what was previously used to get those values directly, but has been deprecated because the others are more accurate. The best practice would be to use something like `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`, as the Compass sample does, and get the yaw/pitch/roll angles by calling the math helpers on that vector. (The Compass already computes yaw and pitch, so taking that code and modifying it to also get roll should be a small task.)